# How was Zetsu able to identify the Asura and Indra transmigrants over the years?

Tags: naruto

How did Zetsu know that Madara was Indra's reincarnation ?

Answer (score 1):

Zetsu was created by Kaguya. Essentially, he was her will, ensuring her revival. The Uchiha and Senju clans originated from Kaguya. So I'm pretty sure he'd be able to tell.

Comment: this answeres why but not how :D